# Hilbert gauge and gravitationl waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

I am studying the gravitational waves as a conseguence of the linearized (vacuum) field equation of general relativity.
I have a problem when we write the linearized field equation in the form $\Box h_{\mu\nu}=0$, where $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a small perturbation of the background metric chosen as the Minkoskii one. Now:

From the equation above we have $h_{\mu\nu}=Re(\epsilon_{\mu\nu}e^{ik_{\lambda}x^{\lambda}})$. In order to satisfy the condition so called "Hilbert gauge" that allows us to obtain the form above form the linearized GR equation, I should require:
$$h^{\mu\nu}_{,\nu}=0$$
For me this condition corresponds to $k_{\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}=0$, since $h^{\mu\nu}=Re(\epsilon^{\mu\nu}e^{ik_{\lambda}x^{\lambda}})$ and $h^{\mu\nu}_{,\nu}=ik_{\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}e^{ik_{\lambda}x^{\lambda}}$.

But here [N.Straumann General Relativity](https://archive.org/details/GeneralRelativity/page/n251/mode/1up) it is indicated that the condition that results is: $k_{\mu}\epsilon^{\mu}_{\nu}=0$.

Can someone explain me where I am failing and why the condition suggested by the reference holds?

$\textbf{EDIT with my attempt:}$ Could be due by the fact that $$\epsilon^{\mu}_\nu=\eta_{\nu\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}$$
and so if $k_{\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}=0$ then $k_{\nu}\eta_{\mu\mu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}=k_{\nu}\epsilon^{\nu}_\mu=0 $?
And then if I rename $\mu$ with $\nu$ I  have $k_{\mu}\epsilon^{\mu}_\nu=0$

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/626520/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about this one: $h^{\mu\nu}_{,\nu}=0$ corresponds to $k_{\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}=0$. This is a familiar result for deriving the gravitational waves in the weak field limit.

**And about your question**, $k_{\mu}\epsilon^{\mu}_{\nu}=0$ is simply obtained as

$${\rm{if}}\,\,{k_\nu }{\varepsilon ^{\lambda \nu }} = 0\,\,{\rm{then}}\,{\rm{we}}\,{\rm{also}}\,{\rm{have}}\,\,{\eta _{\lambda \mu }}\underbrace {({k_\nu }{\varepsilon ^{\lambda \nu }})}_{ = 0\,} = 0\,\,{\rm{which}}\,{\rm{means}}\,{\rm{that}}\,{k_\nu }\varepsilon _\mu ^\nu  = 0.$$

Note that I just made use of this relation: ${k_\nu }{\varepsilon ^{\lambda \nu }}=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! so you have just substitued in $k_{\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}=0$ the index $\mu$ with $\lambda$ to write $k_{\nu}\epsilon^{\lambda\nu}=0$, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a free index. Then, I just used the index lowering rule.

Comment: Thanks! Another thing: I really should want from $k_{\nu}\epsilon^{\nu}_\mu=0$ to obtain $k_{\mu}\epsilon^{\mu}_\nu=0$, this could be done considering to remane $\nu$ with $\mu$ and viceversa?

Comment: At this level, yes. ${k_\nu }\varepsilon _\mu ^\nu  = 0$ and ${k_\mu }\varepsilon _\nu ^\mu  = 0$ generally have the same meaning. But, be carful about the free indices since they can represent different components of a tensor. The repeated index $\nu$ in ${k_\nu }\varepsilon _\mu ^\nu  = 0$ or the repeated index $\mu$ in  ${k_\mu }\varepsilon _\nu ^\mu  = 0$ are dummy indices (dummy index : an index that is summed over is a summation index), and any symbol can replace them without changing the meaning of the expression provided that it does not collide with index symbols in the same term.

Comment: To be more specific, if the combination ${k_\mu }\varepsilon _\nu ^\mu $ be a part of a relation, you cannot simply replace it with ${k_\nu }\varepsilon _\mu ^\nu $.

Comment: Ok thanks again a lot!

Comment: Sorry another doubt (the last i promise): this expression ($\epsilon^{\mu}_\nu=\eta_{\nu\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}$) that I have written in the question is wrong?

Comment: Generally, such tonsorial equations with the same repeated and free indices considered as wrong. You should avoid repeating a specific symbol more than two times in a tonsorial equation (It collides with index symbols in the same term and strongly can cause confusion/mistake). So, instead of $\epsilon^{\mu}_\nu=\eta_{\nu\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}$ you have to use this one $\varepsilon _\mu ^\nu  = {\eta _{\mu \lambda }}{\varepsilon ^{\lambda \nu }}$ (here, $\lambda$ is just a dummy index and can be replaced with any other symbol).

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at the book by T. Moore (A general relativity workbook). It's great for learning GR computations, especially for the beginners (It was very useful for me). It covers gravitational waves in a very good manner.

Comment: Thanks thanks again a lot!!